# Estimating prevalence using correlated data from a survey

Tags: correlation, estimation, survey, epidemiology

I have some survey data from a survey.  One of the questions asked the survey respondent (ostensibly an adult) to list the age, height, and weight of all persons living in the household (age, height, and weight are required to compute a person’s BMI and classify the person (adult or child) as obese or not).  The survey was sent out to approximately 3000 households and responses were received from approximately 1000 households.

I would like to estimate the prevalence (proportion of the population) in a particular geography (ZIP Code Tabulation Area ([ZCTA](https://www.census.gov/geo/reference/zctas.html)), and county) that falls into a particular BMI category (Underweight, Normal, Overweight, Obese).  I would like to use as many data points as I can when computing these estimates.  For example, if a particular household had 4 data points (responses for 2 adults and 2 children), I would like to use both adult data points when computing the adult prevalence and both the child data points when computing the child prevalence.  However, I think that using all four responses from that household would bias each estimate because BMI in a family is correlated (see for example https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4380227/ and https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/b06a/a61a20bef712b380b0e258097ca2539afc72.pdf) and the vast majority of households with multiple responses are likely to be families.

One method I think I can use to compute an unbiased estimate is to randomly pick a single data point for any household that has more than one data point associated with it; however this does not take advantage of all of the data and the number of responses at some geographic levels is already quite small.

Thus I would like to use all the data points when computing my estimate, but I am not sure how to account for this correlation.

Comment: you want to avoid selection bias but select all the variables. Do you have an estimate of the correlation in the family data you are dealing with?

Comment: If the dataset you are using, is from an official government survey, it likely provides appropriate weights and clustering and sampling design variables. If this is the case (see the survey documentation), you should be able to use simply feed these variables as parameters into your analysis software and, if properly coded, the software will properly account for the clustering and correlation in your data within household. See SUDAAN software for Research Triangle Institute, the survey procedures in SAS, or the survey package in R.

Comment: By the way, you may want to check out the limited availability datasets from the NHANES.  I believe they allow you to calculate BMI a the ZCTA level and account for household clustering.